# JPA: transaction is committed in the database, but @Version is not incremented

Tags: jpa, ejb

I'm using JPA in a JavaEE application. I have a persistent entity `Stamp`, and I keep getting `OptimisticLockException` (`The object [domain.Stamp@473f5e6] cannot be merged because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read`) every time I try to delete one right after updating it.

It seems that although the edition is committed in the database, the version number never gets incremented in the object (it does in the DB), therefore any subsequent attempt to merge (in order to either update or delete) triggers the exception.

Basically, the scenario goes as follows:

1. Instantiate new `Stamp s`;
2. `em.persist(s);` (version is 1 in both DB and object)
3. Update `s`;
4. `em.merge(s);` (version is 2 in DB, 1 in object)
5. `em.remove(this.em.merge(s));`

Obviously, there's something I don't understand. Why is the object version not updated in spite of the DB commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the fact that `em.merge(s);` will return a merged `Stamp` instance of `s`, be it `s'`. So `s'` will hold the new version after step 4. In your scenario the version field will/should equal 2). Sadly, the original version of the object (`s`) will not reflect the changes (persisted in the database) in it's outdated object state.

After that you could use this version (`s'`) of this `Stamp` instance to remove it in step 5. Note: the second `em.merge(s)` operation in step 5 is not necessary though, as - if the previous return value of the `merge` operation in step 4 is used correctly - it holds the changes of the previous update: reflected in your database but also in the state of the object (`s'`).

See also: 
[javax.persistence.EntityManager.merge(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T))

> Returns:
>   the managed instance that the state was merged to

Comment: Actually I _did_ retrieve the updated reference returned by `merge`, but it was not propagated to the right place in my application. So you're right, I was not looking at the right object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Side comment, the `merge` at step 5 is here because the sequence is not hard-coded, every step is in a different method and the `merge` in step 4 has not necessarily occurred. I agree that it looks odd when presented this way.

Comment: I was wondering why you had the merge in step 5. Maybe, it depends on your architecture for handling persistence issues. But anyway, glad the answer was of help for you